# How to use non-alphabetical symbols respectively characters like '<' and '>' in Tikz qtree node labels?

Tags: symbols

I am trying to use label nodes for a tikz qtree that include the lower-than `<` and greater-than `>`  characters like shown in the first node of the example below. The problem is that instead of showing `<` and `>` some other strange symbols are presented - see first node label of the picture below.

While the second node does solve the problem somehow by just forcing `<` and `>` to be in math-mode I seek for a solution which also forces the text to accept the `\textbf` command it is enclosed in.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree 
        [.\node(html){\textbf{<html>}}; 
        [.\node(html){\textbf{$<$html$>$}}; ]
        ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

1. Is there a solution?
2. What is the reason for this - in my eyes - strange behavior?

Comment: Use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} works ... but why?

Comment: @peter-m you can find a possible explanation in my answer below

Comment: Just a note about method and problem diagnosis for future reference: your example has nothing to do with `tikz-qtree` or `tikz` at all. This is why constructing true minimal examples is important in diagnosing problems.  The minimal example that shows the problem is simply a document that contains just `<>` and no other packages loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `\textless` and `\textgreater`

from *The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List* (pag. 114)

> The characters “<”, “>”, and “|” do work as expected in math mode,
>   although they produce, respectively, “¡”, “¿”, and “—” in text mode
>   when using the OT1 font encoding.[13] The following are some
>   alternatives for typesetting “<”, “>”, and “|”:
>
> – Specify a document font encoding other than OT1 (as described on page 8).
>
> – Use the appropriate symbol commands from Table 2 on page 9, viz. \textless,
>   \textgreater, and \textbar.
>
> – Enter the symbols in math mode instead of text mode, i.e., $$, and $|$.
>
> [13] Donald Knuth didn’t think such symbols were important outside of mathematics so he omitted them from his text fonts.

Comment: I needed to to greater then or equal to in my or gates so i used $\ge$1 according to this suggestion. Thanks.